# How can I close UIWebView after submitting form in the view?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView that displays a webpage including a feedback form. I want to remove this UIWebView after I submit the form in that view.

How can I do that?

Comment: Depends...how was it created and displayed in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You normally achieve this sort of thing by setting a delegate on the web view, to register for interesting callbacks.

Don't forget to nil the delegate before you dispose of the web view or you might experience a crash.

Answer (score 0):

In the delegate for the UIWebView, within 
    webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:
search for a the url triggered by the form submission. If it's present, set a flag value.

Then, in your delegate's webViewDidFinishLoad: method, if the flag is set, remove the webView.

Answer (score 0):

Well You Have not made clear of your allocation of your webview or not familiar with your code .I guess you want to return to previous view from the UIWebView , in that case you can simply the push the viewcontroller containing the webview through a UINavigationController and get back to the view on back button or set a flag in webviewDidStartLoad and webViewDidFinishLoad and remove the view when the flag is set in DidFinish Part else please elaborate your problem.